Realize a quantum channel which is expressed by Kraus operators
I have a quantum channel which can be expressed by Kraus operators, but the channel will add another Hilbert space to the original one, like from HA to HA tensor HB. How can I construct a unitary operator and ancilla systems to realize this channel? I have searched for related notes but they all talk about channels that do not change the dimension of the Hilbert space.

Thanks for your question! Such a channel is not (to our knowledge) physically possible, because this additional Hilbert space must have always existed.
It is not that your channel creates this Hilbert space, but that it maps a state which was originally confined to a subspace (i.e. $H_A$) to the entire space (i.e. $H_A\otimes H_B$).
Therefore, to construct this channel, represent your original state in this new, enlarged space (essentially by adding zeros), and define your Kraus operators over the same.
